# Dialog not apper using v-show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

Im trying to popup a login dialog but the problem i cannot make appear even I set it 'true'. below is my two components that appear on main layout.

**login components:**

```
<template>
  <div v-show="true">
    <q-dialog>
        <q-card>
          <q-card-section>
            <q-form class="q-gutter-md" style="width: 400px">
              <h4 class="text-h4 text-primary q-my-auto text-weight-medium">Login</h4>
              <q-input
              filled
              :error="state.error"
              label="Your email *"
              lazy-rules
              :rules="[ required, email ]"
              />

              <q-input
                filled
                v-model="state.doc.password"
                :error-message="state.error ? 'Incorrect email or password' : 'Field is Required'"
                :error="state.error"
                :type="state.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                label="Password *"
                lazy-rules
                :rules="[ required ]">
              </q-input>
            </div>
          </q-form>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </q-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import part here...
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    //other function here...
})
</script>
```

**other components that call login component as dialog:**

```
<template>
  <LoginComponents />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import LoginComponents from 'components/LoginComponents'
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    LoginComponents
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`q-dialog` needs to know it should be shown.

There are examples of how to use that component here.
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/dialog

```
<q-dialog v-model="isShownWhenThisIsTrue">
```

Comment: so how do I call the method from other component